# Find the path of JSON for a key value

Tags: javascript, json, jsonpath

```
jSon = {
        "id":"node1",
        "name":"Languages",
        "rel":"",
        "children":1,
        "step":1,
        "path":1,
        "nodes":[
            {
                "id":"node2",
                "name":"Java",
                "rel":"Pure Object Oriented Prog",
                "children":1,
                "step":2,
                "path":2,
                "nodes":[
                    {
                        "id":"node3",
                        "name":"C#",
                        "rel":"Framework",
                        "children":0,
                        "step":3,
                        "path":3,
                        "nodes":[]
                    },{
                        "id":"node4",
                        "name":"C++",
                        "rel":"OOPS",
                        "children":0,
                        "step":3,
                        "path":4,
                        "nodes":[]
                    }]
            }]
    };
```

For above structure, how do I get path of id(key) = node3(value)

(i.e) `jSon.nodes[0].nodes[1].id`

So that i could able push new Object (i.e) `jSon.nodes[0].nodes.push(newjSon);`

Or is there any other way to add new object in particular position for this structure...
Please suggest some javascript code.. No jQuery

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Are you asking how to access a particular node and push into it or are you asking if there is any way to simplify the process of pushing to a node nested very deep in your object?

Comment: @David. Yeah, I wanna push new node in particular position...

Comment: Have you considered writing a function for your object that simplifies the process for pushing a node into it? This could be useful to automate code like `JSon.nodes[0].nodes.push(newJSon);`

Comment: @David you saying that, i should make a change in JSON structure..

Comment: Ah, yes, scratch that. That's a bad idea. However, if you want to simplify it, you should still write a function that will take `JSON.parse(JSon)` and push appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

```
var somethingElse = "data_you_want_to_push"; // not in JSON
var myObject = JSON.parse(jSon);

myObject.nodes.forEach ( function(singleNodeLevel1){
   singleNodeLevel1.nodes.push(somethingElse);
});

jSon = JSON.stringify(myObject);
```

you can add counter and increase it within forEach loop if you need that, or use just

```
if (singleNodeLevel1.id === "something") singleNodeLevel1.nodes.push(somethingElse);
```

this is without JQuery, but requires support of ECMAScript5 in your browser, IE8 and earlier don't support it, but you can add a "shim" for it if your browser doesn't support it